# Integração entre Magento e Moodle

Tags: magento, moodle

Eu quero vender cursos do [Moodle](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moodle) 2.6+ via [Magento](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento) 1.7.

O fluxo do processo é como se segue:

- Usuário cria uma conta no Magento (carrinho de compras).
- Usuário compra um curso.
- Após adquirir o curso, o usuário pode entrar no Moodle com os mesmos dados de login com o qual o usuário foi registrado no Magento.
- Usuário deve estar inscrito no curso comprado.

Como posso fazer essa integração?

*obs.: Se possível com View SQL.*

Answer (score 1):

Esse tipo de integração pode ser feito sim, porém depende da forma que você deseja estrutura sua aplicação.
Nada impede que, quando um usuário compre um curso, o sistema gere um login e senha para ele no banco de dados do Moodle e envie esses dados por e-mail, dando acesso assim, não só ao Moodle como também o inscrevendo no curso desejado.

Comment: Sim, isso eu sei. Eu criei view na tabela do Magento para "pegar" os dados que eu preciso mas o Moodle não reconhece os ids dos cursos comprados.

Comment: Estou usando Banco de Dados Externo tanto para inscrição quanto para matriculados e sincronizo tudo com crontab.
Mas esta difícil fazer as inscrições dos cursos.